# graphical problems after update Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, updates, gui

I've just updated Ubuntu and restarted my computer.

Now my desktop is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV4Pv.jpg).

It has been like this for few days and now I noticed I can't run any video on VLC either.

I want to update Ubuntu again but it says no new file for update.

How i can fix this?

`lspci -k` :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 510 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics 510
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP PMC
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
    Subsystem: AzureWave QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Updates don't always play nice, if it was an upgrade, please try a clean install

Comment: @AskingOverFlow Which video adapter do you have, with which driver? Please add the output of `lspci -k` and `lsmod | grep drm`  to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert ```lspci -k``` added. ```grep drm``` prints nothing.

Comment: You have to try installation of drivers with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and reboot after this.